# Excluir ImageButton num ScrollView no Android

Tags: android

Estamos desenvolvendo uma prancha de comunicação para pessoas com certo grau de dificiência, poder se comunicar através de uma prancha de comunicação. No caso pode ser que sem querer, adicione mais de uma imagem ( ficar duplicado ), então eu precisaria excluir este último botão.

Como o uso é para quem tem certo grau de dificuldade, pensamos em deixar a função de excluir em um botão ( conforme indica na imagem circulado em vermelho ), que ao ser pressionado, excluir o último ImageButton adicionado.

Alguma idéia de como fazer isso? Ele está adicionado num LinearLayout, numa ScroolView.

Abaixo está o código para adicionar o botão

```
//Função para Criar Botões
    protected void criaBotoes(final int idBotao, final int posicaoX, final int posicaoY, final int altura, final int largura, int tipoLayout, int tipoBotao, String pathArquivo, final int tagBotao) {
        AssetManager manager = getAssets(); //Pasta onde ficam os arquivos a serem carregados ( Imagens )

        //Carrega Imagens dinamicamente
        InputStream open = null;
        try {
            open = manager.open(pathArquivo);                 //Seta nome para carregar o arquivo
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(open); //Seta objeto para controle de imagem

            //Cria Layout Params ( "Fatias no layout para adiocionar cada botão )
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            //Seta posições e tamanho do Botão
            params.leftMargin = posicaoX;
            params.topMargin  = posicaoY;
            params.width      = altura;
            params.height     = largura;

            ImageButton botaoImg = new ImageButton(this); //Cria Botão Dinamicamente
            botaoImg.setId(idBotao);                      //Seta propriedade ID para cada usuário, para ser usado no "Click"
            botaoImg.setTag(tagBotao);                    //**
            botaoImg.setBackgroundResource(0);            //Deixa botão sem bordas

            botaoImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int id  = v.getId();
                    int tag = (int) v.getTag();
                    //...
                }
            });

            botaoImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  //Seta objeto de imagem para o Botão
            botaoImg.setLayoutParams(params); //Seta layout para o botão ( "Fatias"  para cada botão )

            ll.addView(botaoImg); //Adiciona Botão no Layout (Linear)
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

criaBotoes(seqBotoesSel, posX, posY, altura, largura, 1, 1, pathAquivo, 0);  
sv.addView(ll); //adiciona botão na ScrollView
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: não entendir...

Comment: Há um ditado que diz: "É melhor prevenir do que remediar". Assim sendo o que deve fazer é prevenir que um botão repetido seja inserido. No entanto, quer queira prevenir ou remediar, a abordagem que está a utilizar para gerir o botões não é a mais adequada para facilitar essa opção. Considere usar uma ListView/RecyclerView para o efeito.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pelo retorno... enquanto saí aqui pro almoço, pensei nisso, porque não então controlar para não deixar adicionar duplicado?... isso é fácil, posso salvar o nome da última figura adicionada, e se a próxima for igual não deixo adicionar... até aí tranquilo, mas pode ter uma situação que selecionou errado ( como quando escrevemos e precisa apagar ), neste caso volto a situação anterior, de precisar excluir o último...